# selecting contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts

I made an app which would retrieve all the contacts stored.I want to make an app which will allow the user to select the contacts which he wants to add to the app.
Should i create checkboxes dynamically and retrieve the selected contacts or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

this is a example, as like u need to work

```
     // MainActivity

      public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   final ListView listTags = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listPack);
   listTags.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, mStrings));
   listTags.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
               int position, long id) {
           listTags.setSelection(position);
```

//               Toast.makeText(getParent(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       });

```
}


 private String[] mStrings = {

    "Comte", "Coolea", "Cooleney", "Coquetdale", "Corleggy", "Cornish Pepper",
    "Cotherstone", "Cotija", "Cottage Cheese", "Cottage Cheese (Australian)",
    "Cougar Gold", "Coulommiers", "Coverdale", "Crayeux de Roncq", "Cream Cheese",
    "Cream Havarti", "Crema Agria", "Crema Mexicana", "Creme Fraiche", "Crescenza",
    "Croghan", "Crottin de Chavignol", "Crottin du Chavignol", "Crowdie", "Crowley",
    "Cuajada", "Curd", "Cure Nantais", "Curworthy", "Cwmtawe Pecorino",
   };
```

// Main xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listPack"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

// list_item.xml // layout

Comment: could you please give me a brief explanation of your code.I am not able to comprehend it.

Comment: see this
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/